# AngularJS how do I $compile an element with an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't seem to figure this one out.  I need to use $compile (I think), to wire up an element with the scope.  This works for elements without another directive (specifically ng-repeat).. but does not work for an element with an ng-repeat.  I've come up with an example:

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nmn7n631iijP1lQAZaXv?p=preview

```
var count = 0;
angular.module("dir", [])

.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 1;
})

.directive('ngHello', function($compile) {
  return {
    scope: true,
    compile: function(telem, attrs, transclude) {
      var repeat = "<div>"+
      "<div ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</div>"+
      "</div>";
      var r = angular.element(repeat);
      telem.after(r);

      var easy = "<div>this is {{test2}}</div>";
      var e = angular.element(easy);
      telem.after(e);


      return {
        pre: function(scope, ielem, iAttrs, controller) {
          $compile(r)(scope); //why doesn't this seem to work?
          $compile(e)(scope);
        },
        post: function(scope, ielem, iAttrs, controller) {
          scope.items = [];
          for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            scope.items.push(count++);
          }
          scope.test2 = "test4";
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I played with your plunk a bit, here is a fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/Tc4fCh7zcGZvs8utvuZl?p=preview

Comment: that works - I guess i was over complicating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call angular.element, $compile will take html. You don't even really need to use the compile function of the directive, this could all be done in the link function. $compile returns the compiled element. You need to use that as the element to add.

Relevant bits from the plunkr:

```
.directive('ngHello', function($compile) {
  var repeat = "<div>"+
  "<div ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</div>"+
  "</div>";
  var r = angular.element(repeat);
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.items = [];
      scope.items.push(1);
      scope.items.push(2);
      scope.items.push(3);
      var e = $compile(repeat)(scope);
      elem.after(e);
```

Comment: yup, this works - I thought modifying the "templated" element would be more.. efficient?  Here, the template has already been compiled and added to the dom, right?  So now I'm modifying the document and not just some fragment..  Any idea why it doesn't work the way I had it?

Comment: $compile does not add the element, it just creates it.